# Accordion .glyphicon-chevron-up and .glyphicon-chevron-down not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using an Accordion with up and down arrows -when run first time down arrow is displayed so user had to click to see data - the data is shown on clicking the down arrow but the up arrow is still shown and doesn't revert to up...I have a Javascript function which does the checking...

Followed this link:-
https://www.bootply.com/113766#

Javascript to change the arrows:-

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
      $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
      $(this).parent().find(
      ".glyphicon-chevron-up").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up")
      .addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");

    }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function ()
    {
        $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-chevron-down")
        .removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron- 
        up");
    });
 });
```

HTML:-

```
<div class="accordion">
<h4 class="up">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
       Testing
        <span class="glyphicon  glyphicon-chevron-up" style="float: right"></span>
    </a>

</h4>


<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse">
```

The default arrow is always displayed - the data is displayed on click

[image]

Comment: Can you please reproduce your problem on  https://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @NafeesAnwar tried to reproduce on JSFiddle but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was pointing to the wrong JQuery version - all working now...